# Asp.net destroy session by sessionid

Tags: asp.net, session, destroy

When one user login my site, this user have a session[sessionid like:xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx], when he login again elsewhere, he have a different session[sessionid like:yyyy-yyyy-yy-yyy], HOW CAN I DESTROPY THE PREVIOUS SESSION[sessionid like:xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx],after he login again with session[sessionid like:yyyy-yyyy-yy-yyy].

**Destroy one session in another sesson!**
Is this possible?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean "he login again elsewhere"? What you are asking should not be necessary. Sounds like you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't worry about that, if you should worry it means your app design is bad.

put a logger in the `Global.asax` in the `Session_End` event and you will be able to track when unused sessions are closed by reading the log file.

Comment: it's not what i want. when this user login again, you find the previous session is still there, also can do sth, because they have different sessionid. i wanna destroy the previous session for security. Thank you anyway.

Comment: try use different browsers (IE,FF,CHROME...) login same site.

Comment: got it, check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645102/opening-a-new-browser-window-with-a-new-session-id-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a lot of confusion regarding this request. I believe this individual wants to know how to prevent concurrent user sessions.

The proposed method: When a user logs in successfully, make this new user sessions active and abandon any other existing active sessions for the user.

My solution:

1. Upon Login, save the SessionID to a database, referenced to the user's account
2. In the Site Master file (or any file you may share with all the pages of your site), compare the current SessionID (HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID) with the Saved SessionID.
3. If the two do not match, Abandon the session (Session.Abandon).

It's a simple solution, but it should address the issue.